# How to i search and sort by use zii.widgets.grid.CGridView when my column there is not in table and attributes?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I want to show list of my attributes (id, name, price, discount) and (total_price)column that is not an attribute.

when I use this code, it shows table of data but I can not search or sort in column (total_price)

Can anyone hep me?

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'product-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
            'header' =>'Price',
            'name'=>'price',
            'value'=>'$data->price',
    ),
    array(
            'header' =>'Discount',
            'name'=>'discount',
            'value'=>'$data->discount',
    ),
    array(
            'header' =>'total price',// total price doesn't save in Data Base
            'name'=>'total_price',
            'value'=>'total_price - (total_price * $data->discount/100)',
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

));
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put on $model->search() method this:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->select = "t.*, t.price - (t.price * t.discount/100) as total_price";

// EDITED: Added for Sort:
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->attributes = array(
                        'defaultOrder'=>'name ASC',
                        'total_price'=>array(
                            'asc'=>'total_price ASC',
                            'desc'=>'total_price DESC',
                          ),
                          '*', // Add order in the other fields.
                    );

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>$sort, // Added to sort.
);
```

And create a not persistence attribute on "Product" model Class:

```
public $total_price;
```

Finally put 'total_price' on rules() in array with ('safe', 'on'=>'search'), something like this:

```
array('id, name, price, discount, total_price', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
```

Comment: Thank you but it only shows list of data And not search or sort!
And i solve the search by putting on $model->search() method this:  $criteria->compare('t.price - (t.price * t.discount/100)',$this->total_price,true);

Comment: With my solution you can put the same '$criteria->compare('t.total_price', $this->total_price);'.

Comment: when I use from ( $criteria->compare('t.total_price', $this->total_price) ), this error occurs:
Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.total_price' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_product` `t` WHERE t.total_price LIKE :ycp0

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry. For Count, etc. you need use 'having'. Something like: 
if(!empty($model->total_price)) $criteria->having = "total_price = $model->total_price";

Comment: But you've removed the '$criteria->compare('t.total_price'...)' ?